# How can I sum of two number factoriel recursivley?

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

I want to calculate sum of two numbers factorial using recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int faktoriyel(int t, int k);

int main ()
{
    int sayi, k, flag, t;

    scanf("%d", &t);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    flag = faktoriyel(t, k);    
    printf("%d", faktoriyel(t, k));
    return 0;
}

int faktoriyel(int sayi, int sayi2)
{
    if(sayi == 1 || sayi == 0)
       return 1;
    else
       return (sayi * faktoriyel(sayi-1)) + (sayi2 * faktoriyel(sayi2-1));
}
```

I try this shape but this code have to argument fail. How can I fix it?
I must use `faktoriyel(int sayi, int sayi2)` function. I can not add other functions.
Also, I must use `sayi1`, `sayi2` parameters.

Comment: You want to sum factorials of two numbers? How about getting single factorial to work first?

Comment: you do not need `flag` or calculating the value twice

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int faktoriyel (int sayi,int sayi2)
> {
>         if (sayi == 1 || sayi == 0 )
>                 return 1;
>         else
>                 return (sayi * faktoriyel(sayi-1))+(sayi2*faktoriyel(sayi2-1));
> }
> ```

you first define the function as taking 2 parameters... yet later you recurse (twice) with 1 single argument.
Maybe you need two functions??

Comment: int faktoriyel (int sayi,int sayi2) I can only use this function.Also I must use 2 parameter sayi,sayi2 in one function.

Comment: so, what should be the value of `faktoriyel(2, 3)`? and of `faktoriyel(3)`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your function's name to `faktoriyel2`, then create a new function to calculate the factorial of a single number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int faktoriyel(int n);
int faktoriyel2 (int t,int k);

int main ()
{
    int k,t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    scanf("%d",&k);

        printf("%d", faktoriyel2(t,k));
        return 0;
}

int faktoriyel(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
      return 1;
    else
      return n * faktoriyel(n - 1);
}

int faktoriyel2 (int sayi,int sayi2)
{

        if (sayi == 1 || sayi == 0 )
                return 1;
        else
                return (sayi * faktoriyel(sayi-1))+(sayi2*faktoriyel(sayi2-1));

}
```